# Loop on table (Without using cursor) to concate data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Please see/run the following script.

```
DECLARE @Products Table (   PId int )

INSERT @Products SELECT 100
INSERT @Products SELECT 101
INSERT @Products SELECT 102

DECLARE @Stff Table ( Stid int, StaffName VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT @Stff SELECT 301, 'White'
INSERT @Stff SELECT 302, 'Green'

DECLARE @Items Table
(
    ItemId int,
    PIdFK int,
    StIdFK int,
    CreatedDate DateTime,
    Notes varchar(100),
    NotesHistory varchar(2000)
)

INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 1, 100, 301, GETDATE(), Null, NULL
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 2, 101, 301, GETDATE(), Null, NULL
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 3, 101, 301, DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE()), 'Hello Dear', NULL
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 4, 101, 301, DATEADD(DD, 2, GETDATE()), 'Did you get my msg?', NULL
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 5, 102, 302, GETDATE(), Null, NULL
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 6, 102, 302, DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE()), Null, NULL
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 7, 102, 302, DATEADD(DD, 3, GETDATE()), 'How are you doing?', NULL
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 8, 102, 302, DATEADD(DD, 4, GETDATE()), 'Your Items are ready.', NULL

SELECT * FROM @Items

DECLARE @ItemsHistory Table
(
    ItemHisotryId int,
    ItemIdFK int,
    StIdFK int,
    NotesHisotry varchar(200),
    CreatedDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 1, 1, 301, NULL, GETDATE()
INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 2, 2, 301, NULL, GETDATE()
INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 3, 3, 301, 'Hello Dear', DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 4, 4, 301, 'Dimd you get my msg?', DATEADD(DD, 2, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 5, 5, 302, NULL, GETDATE()
INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 6, 6, 302, NULL, DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 7, 7, 302, 'How are you doing?', DATEADD(DD, 3, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @ItemsHistory SELECT 8, 8, 302, 'Your Items are ready', DATEADD(DD, 4, GETDATE())
```

I want to concat all data in `Notes` column of Items table and `NotsHistory` column of ItemsHistory table into one string, In-fact I want to update `Items.NotesHistory` column of Items table with all `ItemsHistory.NotesHisotry` column related on `PID`

Can you please help this without using cursor. I am using sql server 2008 so CTE can do this but I am not getting that how I can achieve this.

The resultant string should be like following

```
<b>Items.CreaedDate - Items.StaffName: <b/> Items.Notes <br/><b>ItemsHisotryCreatedDate - ItemsHistory.StaffName <b> ItemsHistory.NotesHistory
```

Following part will be added from ItemsHistory table on each record added for unique 'PId'

```
<br/><b>ItemsHisotryCreatedDate - ItemsHistory.StaffName <b> ItemsHistory.NotesHistory
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  PIdFK,
                Notes,
                ItemIdFK
        FROM    @ItemsHistory ih INNER JOIN
                @Items i    ON  ih.ItemIdFK = i.ItemId
        WHERE   Notes IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
        v.PIdFK,
        STUFF( 
               (SELECT 
                    ', ' + v2.Notes 
                    FROM Vals v2 
                    WHERE v.PIdFK=v2.PIdFK 
                    ORDER BY v2.ItemIdFK 
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
               ).value('.','varchar(max)') 
               ,1,2, '' 
          ) AS Notes 
FROM Vals v 
GROUP BY v.PIdFK
```

Comment: Thanks astander, the result is not what I am looking i.e.
'101 Did you get my msg?, Hello Dear, How are you doing?, Your Items are ready.'
'102 Did you get my msg?, Hello Dear, How are you doing?, Your Items are ready.'

The result should be 
'101 Hello Dear Did you get my msg'
'102 How are you doing Your Items are ready'
Sorry for the formatting.

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate without the loop via something like below; just add in your own query / joins etc as necessary:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max) = ''

SELECT @s = @s + '<br/><b>' + CONVERT(varchar(10), i.CreatedDate, 101) + '</b>' + ISNULL(i.Notes, '')
FROM @Items i

SELECT @s
```

(you **must** make sure there are no `NULL`s in there)

## but do not do this!

The database is ***not*** the place to build html; not least, it opens you up *hugely* to XSRF vulnerabilities. I would do this in the UI layer, making appropriate use of the html-encoding functions provided by whichever platform you are using. Blindly concatenating strings as html is pretty much on a par with blindly concatenating user strings into TSQL (instead of using parameters); at best the formatting will be borked (no correct handling of `<`, etc) - at worst you place your users at direct risk of attack.

Comment: Thanks Marc, and Thanks for the 'XSRF vulnerabilities' suggestion. In fact I am doing this in my UI but I had changed my db design and need to update the Items table. Thats why I just want to run the script and update the column. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @pst only if it is xhtml, not html .... but *possibly*. It would depend a lot on the scenario. And the free-floating `<br/>` could be a pain.