# How to email query output

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, smtp, sql-server-2000

I have a basic query, and i'd like to email the results.  How can I do this at the query level?  So if my query is:

```
SELECT 
    Store_Id, Paid_Out_Amount, Paid_Out_Comment, 
    Paid_Out_Datetime, Update_UserName
FROM Paid_Out_Tb
WHERE (Store_Id = 1929) OR
      (Paid_Out_Amount > 50) AND 
      (Paid_Out_Datetime BETWEEN 
             CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-01 00:00:00', 102) AND 
             CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-30 00:00:00', 102))
```

How would I email the output?  I have a procedure to send email via SMTP and the parameters are `@From, @To, @Subject` and `@body`... which works.. How would I make the body the outcome of the query?

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SQLNotify] 
   @From varchar(100) ,
   @To varchar(100) ,
   @Subject varchar(100)=" ",
   @Body varchar(4000) = "Test"
/*********************************************************************

This stored procedure takes the above parameters and sends an e-mail. 
All of the mail configurations are hard-coded in the stored procedure. 
Comments are added to the stored procedure where necessary.
Reference to the CDOSYS objects are at the following MSDN Web site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cdosys/html/_cdosys_messaging.asp

***********************************************************************/ 
   AS
   Declare @iMsg int
   Declare @hr int
   Declare @source varchar(255)
   Declare @description varchar(500)
   Declare @output varchar(1000)

--************* Create the CDO.Message Object ************************
   EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'CDO.Message', @iMsg OUT

--***************Configuring the Message Object ******************
-- This is to configure a remote SMTP server.
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cdosys/html/_cdosys_schema_configuration_sendusing.asp
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing").Value','2'
-- This is to configure the Server Name or IP address. 
-- Replace MailServerName by the name or IP of your SMTP Server.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver").Value', '10.1.1.10' 

-- Save the configurations to the message object.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Configuration.Fields.Update', null

-- Set the e-mail parameters.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'To', @To
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'From', @From
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Subject', @Subject

-- If you are using HTML e-mail, use 'HTMLBody' instead of 'TextBody'.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'TextBody', @Body
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Send', NULL

-- Sample error handling.
   IF @hr <>0 
     select @hr
     BEGIN
       EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetErrorInfo NULL, @source OUT, @description OUT
       IF @hr = 0
         BEGIN
           SELECT @output = '  Source: ' + @source
           PRINT  @output
           SELECT @output = '  Description: ' + @description
           PRINT  @output
         END
       ELSE
         BEGIN
           PRINT '  sp_OAGetErrorInfo failed.'
           RETURN
         END
     END


-- Clean up the objects created.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @iMsg

   PRINT 'Mail Sent!'



GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

This is the procedure i'm using to send the mail... which works... I just want to add a spot in it to send the results of the query above it...  Can this be done easily within in the procedure?

Comment: Do you want to send the entire query output to a single person, or do you want to send each line to someone different?

Comment: I would like to send the entire output to a single person... It's usually only 5 lines of output...

Comment: The problem is it's Server 2000... which means the sp_send_dbmail procedure will not work... Not sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Server Powershell pack. An example (with detailed explanation) of using it to obtain output is [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1684/powershell-support-in-sql-server-2008-with-the-invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet/).

(The above is taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553190/1180926), but to clarify something s/he says: SQL Server 2008 client components is required (Express should be fine), but it can work with SQL Server 2000 databases ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281962%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)).)

Comment: This seems more complicated that I thought it would be.  My initial though is there had to be some sort of backwards compatible send mail procedure... Or at least a way to add a way to get the query results and email them from the procedure... right now I have a procedure that emails fine, just does not use the results...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a variable for a direct loop concatenation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447564/1180926 (although you would use tab and newline delimiters instead of HTML code).

You would then just change your query accordingly, store it in `@Body`, and you're done!

Comment: Can I just call my procedure and assign @body to the query?

Comment: No, you have to use that string trick. You can only assign the last line of a query to a string - the variable concatenation is a hack to get around that.